# Security feature: EditTextPreference no bigger then 100?

Tags: android, edittextpreference

Is it possible in Android to limit what is the maximum and minimum number that user can input in `EditTextPreference`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may use [OnPreferenceChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener.html) to catch the user input and validate, possibly preventing it from being written to the Preferences by returning true/false.